# Grep line without include double quote

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I trying to `grep` a line which have double quotes. How can I do it without including double quotes.

```
export port="$(find ./pdf/myInventory/dyn_conf/group_vars/abc1/vars.yml -exec sh -c 'grep -A 3 -e ilink_nei_sri_host {} | grep -e port' \; | cut -d: -f2)"

export port_https=$(($abc_port + 81))

find ./pdf/myInventory/dyn_conf/group_vars/abc1/vars.yml  \
    -exec sed -i -e 's/port: \"${port}\"/port: \"${port_https}\"/g' {} \;
```

However, if the port has double quotes eg for port value: `"20080"`
Im trying to replace with the port_https value and it become `" "20080""`
How can i make it just just to `"20080"`?

Comment: Why would you run `find` on a single file?  Simply `sed` it.

Comment: could you change this;  export port_https=$(echo $(($abc_port + 81))| sed 's/ //g')